# How do I view Mozilla TTS training performance in Tensorboard?

Tags: text-to-speech, tensorboard, mozilla

A lot of the documentation for Mozilla TTS mentions examining graphs in Tensorboard or posting Tensorboard graphs to the forums. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within your local copy of the `mozilla-tts` project, run:

```
./bin/tensorboard --logdir path/to/your/run-output/directory
```

... where `path/to/your/run-output/directory` is the path to the run output directory. The path is a combination of what's in the `output_path` setting in your `config.json` file, coupled with the type of model, and date and time training started. During training, Mozilla TTS writes an ever-increasing `tfevents` file into the folder -- this is the file Tensorboard reads.

For example, my run output directory path is `/home/guy/moz-tts/Models/test/test-ddc-March-07-2021_11+23AM-547bfc4` so the command I run is:

```
./bin/tensorboard --logdir /home/guy/moz-tts/Models/test/test-ddc-March-07-2021_11+23AM-547bfc4
```

After running the command, you can view your Tensorboard graphs at http://localhost:6006/. You can run Tensorboard multiple times; each instance gets assigned a unique port number (`6007`, `6008`, `6009`, etc.)

[image: An example of what Tensorboard looks like]